# installing sql_server in a windows server 2003 R2 (VM)

Tags: chef-recipe, chef-solo, chef-infra

```
[2014-08-08T00:54:28+00:00] INFO: *** Chef 11.8.2 ***
[2014-08-08T00:54:28+00:00] INFO: Chef-client pid: 2580
[2014-08-08T00:54:37+00:00] INFO: Setting the run_list to ["recipe[sql_server::default]"] from JSON
[2014-08-08T00:54:37+00:00] INFO: Run List is [recipe[sql_server::default]]
[2014-08-08T00:54:37+00:00] INFO: Run List expands to [sql_server::default]
[2014-08-08T00:54:37+00:00] INFO: Starting Chef Run for AMAZON-7D4172E3.ec2.internal
[2014-08-08T00:54:37+00:00] INFO: Running start handlers
[2014-08-08T00:54:37+00:00] INFO: Start handlers complete.
[2014-08-08T00:54:38+00:00] INFO: Processing windows_package[Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Native Client] action install (sql_server::client line 26)
[2014-08-08T00:54:39+00:00] INFO: Installing windows_package[Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Native Client] version latest
[2014-08-08T00:54:39+00:00] INFO: Processing remote_file[C:\chef\cache/sqlncli.msi] action create (dynamically defined)
[2014-08-08T00:54:39+00:00] INFO: Starting installation...this could take awhile.
[2014-08-08T00:54:40+00:00] INFO: Running queued delayed notifications before re-raising exception
[2014-08-08T00:54:40+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
[2014-08-08T00:54:40+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
[2014-08-08T00:54:40+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to C:/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
[2014-08-08T00:54:40+00:00] FATAL: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: windows_package[Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Native Client] (sql_server::client line 26) had an error: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: Expected process to exit with [0, 42, 127], but received '1603'
---- Begin output of msiexec /qn /i "C:\chef\cache\sqlncli.msi" IACCEPTSQLNCLILICENSETERMS=NO ----
STDOUT: 
STDERR: 
---- End output of msiexec /qn /i "C:\chef\cache\sqlncli.msi" IACCEPTSQLNCLILICENSETERMS=NO ----
Ran msiexec /qn /i "C:\chef\cache\sqlncli.msi" IACCEPTSQLNCLILICENSETERMS=NO returned 1603
[2014-08-08T00:54:35+00:00] WARN: unable to detect ip6address
[0m
================================================================================[0m
[31mError executing action `install` on resource 'windows_package[Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Native Client]'[0m
================================================================================[0m

[0m
Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed[0m
------------------------------------[0m
Expected process to exit with [0, 42, 127], but received '1603'
---- Begin output of msiexec /qn /i "C:\chef\cache\sqlncli.msi" IACCEPTSQLNCLILICENSETERMS=NO ----
STDOUT: 
STDERR: 
---- End output of msiexec /qn /i "C:\chef\cache\sqlncli.msi" IACCEPTSQLNCLILICENSETERMS=NO ----
Ran msiexec /qn /i "C:\chef\cache\sqlncli.msi" IACCEPTSQLNCLILICENSETERMS=NO returned 1603[0m

[0m
Resource Declaration:[0m
---------------------[0m
# In C:/chef/cookbooks/sql_server/recipes/client.rb

 26:     windows_package node['sql_server'][pkg]['package_name'] do
 27:       source node['sql_server'][pkg]['url']
 28:       checksum node['sql_server'][pkg]['checksum']
 29:       installer_type :msi
 30:       options "IACCEPTSQLNCLILICENSETERMS=#{node['sql_server']['accept_eula'] ? 'YES' : 'NO'}"
 31:       action :install
 32:     end
 33: 
[0m

[0m
Compiled Resource:[0m
------------------[0m
# Declared in C:/chef/cookbooks/sql_server/recipes/client.rb:26:in `block in from_file'

windows_package("Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Native Client") do
  action [:install]
  retries 0
  retry_delay 2
  cookbook_name :sql_server
  recipe_name "client"
  source "http://download.microsoft.com/download/B/6/3/B63CAC7F-44BB-41FA-92A3-CBF71360F022/1033/x86/sqlncli.msi"
  checksum "35c4b98f7f5f951cae9939c637593333c44aee920efbd4763b7bdca1e23ac335"
  installer_type :msi
  options "IACCEPTSQLNCLILICENSETERMS=NO"
  package_name "Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Native Client"
  timeout 600
  success_codes [0, 42, 127]
end
[0m

[0m
```

I'm trying to get installed sql_server cookbook in a WindowsServer 2003 VM.... I know that this cookbook that I'm using https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/sql_server it's only tested for WS2008 but if someone can help me to follow the errors that I have until I get this cookbook for WS2003 I'm gonna be very grateful!

Comment: Have you tried changing `IACCEPTSQLNCLILICENSETERMS=NO` to `YES`?

Comment: @sethvargo `ILIKETHATVARIABLENAME` :)

Comment: @sethvargo I will try and I will let you know what happen:)....

Answer (score 0):

Update the cookbook so that msiexec uses the /qb switch, as opposed to /qn. This will install using only the most basic user interface, as opposed to none at all - which shouldn't be an issue.

I don't know why this works, but it did the trick for me.

So, to elaborate a little, in /recipes/client.rb, change lines 26-32 to this:

```
windows_package node['sql_server'][pkg]['package_name'] do
  source node['sql_server'][pkg]['url']
  checksum node['sql_server'][pkg]['checksum']
  installer_type :msi

  options %W[
     /qb
     IACCEPTSQLNCLILICENSETERMS="YES"
  ].join(' ')

  action :install
end
```

Note I have overwritten the attribute switch that would set IACCEPTSQLNCLILICENSETERMS to 'NO' if the node['sql_server']['accept_eula'] attribute was set that way - largely to keep the concept of this change as simple as possible (Also, I cant think of any use case where you would actually want to set this as 'NO'?)